# Elastic search: Partial search not working properly

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Partial search is not working on multiple fields.

Data: - "`Sales inquiries generated`".

```
{
    "query_string": {
        "fields": ["name", "title", "description", "subject"],
        "query": search_data+"*"
    }
}
```

- Case1: When I pass search data as "inquiri" it works fine,
  But when I pass search data as "inquirie" it's not working .
- Case2: When I pass search data as "sale" it works fine,
  But when I pass search data as "sales" it's not working.
- Case3: When I pass search data as "generat" it works fine,
  But when I pass search data as "generate" it's not working.

I defined my field this way.

```
text_analyzer = analyzer("text_analyzer", tokenizer="standard", filter=["lowercase", "stop", "snowball"])


name = Text(analyzer=text_analyzer, fields={"raw": Keyword()})
title = Text(analyzer=text_analyzer, fields={"raw": Keyword()})
subject = Text(analyzer=text_analyzer, fields={"raw": Keyword()})
```

What is the issue in my code? Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Already added('Data: - "Sales inquiries generated".')

Comment: Can you paste the results also? How do you say its not working?

Comment: @AbhishekIntellial could you please follow up on your question and let me know if you need further clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to the use of `snowball` token filter which stems the words, please refer [official snowball doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-snowball-tokenfilter.html) for more info.

I create the same analyzer with your setting to see the generated tokens for your text, as at the end search happens when the index token matches the search term tokens.

ES provides nice REST apis and you can easily reproduce the issue:

**Create index with your setting**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "snowball",
                        "stop"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

once index is created you can use the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to see generated tokens for your text.

```
POST http://{{hostname}}:{{port}}/{{index-name}}/_analyze

{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "Sales inquiries generated"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "sale",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "inquiri",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "generat",
            "start_offset": 16,
            "end_offset": 25,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**You can see all the tokens are the same which matches your search query, hence you are getting result for other search terms, which means while querying instead of raw you are using the keyword part of your text field**

Comment: Search analyser also contains `snowball` so `sales` should match? isn't?

Comment: @Gibbs agree but he has not provided his search query and at the end as I mentioned I guess he is using the `.keyword` field on search queries which would not be analyzed

Comment: He is using query string which should use analysed version I suspect.

Comment: @Gibbs we can confirm only when we see the final search JSON :)

Comment: @Gibbs anyway his implementation is not correct and has several flaw, there are various ways to implement a partial search and what he is doing is just simple search with stemming, if you are intrested I wrote a detailed blog https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/ on autocomplete in ES

Comment: Good article. Thanks for it.